# Why for real number we have just one square root whereas for complex number we have two?

Tags: complex-numbers

Intuitively, $\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$ but since $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is defined from $\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R^+$, we have $\sqrt{4}=2$ (if we defined $x\mapsto \sqrt x$ from $\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$, the this function wouldn't be well defined since for example $4$ would have $2$ image).

Why such argument doesn't work for complex number ? (because for complex number $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ is defined $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R^-\to \mathbb C$ For example, $$\sqrt i=\pm \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right).$$

So the complex square root is not well defined ? If yes, why ?

Comment: @Raptor: That's why I precise "for real number" and "for complex number"

Comment: That is because $\mathbf R$ is an ordered field, so we have a canonical way to distinguish the two square roots, and conventionally, we define $\sqrt x$ as the *positive* root. On the contrary, $\mathbf C$ is not an ordered field.

Comment: @Bernard: the result it's still the same : in both case $z\mapsto \sqrt z$  is not well defined... Maybe I didn't understand your answer..

Comment: That's right: there is no continuous function $f$ on $\mathbf C$ such that $\bigl(f(z)\bigr)^2=z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is somewhat of a convention on how to choose which complex number is $\sqrt{z}$. Namely, choose $\sqrt{z} = \exp\left[\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Ln}(x)\right]$, where $\mathrm{Ln}(x)$ is the principal branch of the natural logarithm. This is equivalent to always choosing the root with positive real part, analogous to how with $\mathbb{R}$ the positive root is always chosen. Negative real numbers are then chosen to be the root with positive imaginary part, to preserve $\sqrt{-1} = i$. This is equivalent to writing $z$ as $r e^{i\theta}$, $r \in \mathbb R^+$ and $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$, then defining $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$. This is not without its downsides, of course. For example, it is no longer true in general that $\sqrt{1/z} = 1/\sqrt{z}$. But there were always going to be compromises when pinning down which root to use.

However, this convention is not as widespread as the universal convention that $\sqrt{x}$ is the positive square root of the positive real number $x$. This is because the positive square root has obvious precedence in $\mathbb R$, whereas in $\mathbb C$ the two are usually on more equal footing. The best solution is probably to just acknowledge that $\sqrt{z}$ is ambiguous in a way that $\sqrt{x}$ isn't, and to be sure to state what convention you're using for $\sqrt{z}$ if that's important in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Every nonzero positive real number $a$ has two square roots, in the sense that there are two solutions of $x^2=a$.

Every nonzero complex number $a$ has two square roots, in the sense that there are two solutions of $z^2=a$.

In both cases, if there is a square root of $a$, then there are two square roots. In this sense, the real and the complex case behave the same.

The only difference is that in the real case there is a natural way to distinguish the two square roots by choosing the positive solution of $x^2=a$. This positive solution is what we can *the* square root of $a$.

Comment: Ok, so $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ is not well defined as function from $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R^-\to \mathbb C$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understood your argument. Could you please give precision ? The function $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ from $\mathbb C/\mathbb R^-\to \mathbb C$ is not well defined ? (but it's holomorphic, so it's strange...)

Answer (score 0):

Every complex non-zero number $z$ has exactly two square roots, each of which is the symmetric of the other one. In the specific case of positive real numbers, one of these sequere roots is a positive real root and the other one is its symmetric. If the number is $x$, we denote the positive real root by $\sqrt x$. But it still has *two* real roots: $\pm\sqrt x$. If we are dealing with non-real complex numbers, there is no universally accepted choice between the two square roots.

Comment: So $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ is not a well defined function, right ? But if so How can it be holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R^-\to \mathbb C$ ?

Comment: There is no such a thing as a not well defined function. However, if, for each $z=re^{i\theta}$ ($\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$), we define $\sqrt z=\sqrt re^{\frac{i\theta}2}$, then *this* choice of square root defines a holomorphic function indeed.