# How can I prove that I need to take the same root of a number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I prove that I need to take the same root of a number?

For example :
$$1=1$$
$$\sqrt1 = \sqrt1$$
$$-1 = 1$$
Since $-1$ and $1$ are both solutions to $\sqrt1$. I'm not sure where the mistake is. Any ideas?

Comment: What does $\sqrt a$ actually mean?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972378/why-for-real-number-we-have-just-one-square-root-whereas-for-complex-number-we-h/

Comment: Huh? Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is a well defined function it maps each positive  number $x$, to the unique **positive** number $y$ which  satisfies $y^2=x$.

Comment: Is that the definition of √a? Because isn't the whole point that there are negative and positive solutions? I didn't know that y in y^2 = x had to be positive.

Comment: The point here is that indeed $x^2 =y$ has two solutions, $\sqrt y$ and $-\sqrt y$.

Comment: A site search for [`square root positive negative`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=square+root+positive+negative) yields many duplicate questions.

Comment: You could look at it this way: (Ignoring zero for this discussion ...) If the square root symbol were inherently ambiguous, so that it could be interpreted to mean either a positive or negative value, then we wouldn't need to write $\pm$ in front of it so often. That is, when we solve $p^2=3$ as $p=\pm\sqrt{3}$, we need the $\pm$ precisely because $\sqrt{3}$ alone *means* the positive value but the equation also admits the negative value as a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square roots -- positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from a comment:

> isn't the whole point that there are negative and positive solutions?

As comments have noted, if $x\ge0$ we define $\sqrt{x}$ not as an arbitrary $y$ with $y^2=x$, but as the unique such $y$ with $y\ge0$. This allows us to distinguish one such $y$, namely $\sqrt{x}$, from another, $-\sqrt{x}$ (well, technically they're the same if $x=0$; that's just [the same root twice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial)). So while both roots exist, we can unambiguously give them different labels. So while $1,\,-1$ both square to $1$, they're not both $\sqrt{1}$: one is $-\sqrt{1}$ instead.